# Typescript/Node: Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm seeing the error I specified in my title and none of the existing solutions here seem to help, so I'm hoping someone can give me insight as to what is going on.

I am using Typescript and Node in my project. TS compiles everything just fine...I end up with the following as expected:

```
projectHome/
   dist/
      schema/
          schema.js
      index.js
```

When I run `node ./dist/index.js` from project home, I get the error
cannot find module '/home/me/projectHome/dist/schema/schema' imported from '/home/me/projectHome/dist/index.js'

Relative imports in index.js are as follows:

```
    import express from 'express';
    import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
    import typeDefs from './schema/schema';
```

My schema.ts file contains:

```
    import { ApolloServer, gql } from 'apollo-server-express'
    import { GraphQLScalarType } from 'graphql'

        const typeDefs = gql`
           ...(edited for brevity/sanity)
        `

    export default typeDefs
```

and my typescript file (should this matter at this point since it is Node that is failing??) looks like this:

```
    {
        "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",                         
        "module": "ES6",                         
        "lib": ["ES6"],                          
        "allowJs": true,                         
        "sourceMap": true,                       
        "outDir": "./dist",                      
        "rootDir": "./src",                      
        "strict": true,                          
        "skipLibCheck": true,                    
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true 
    },

    "files": ["src/@types/graphql.d.ts"],
    "include": ["src/**/*", "serverInfo.json"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
    }
```

Note that I cannot use commonjs because some objection related code fails when I do.  Is the problem actually related to using ES6 modules, or is something else wrong?

Thank in advance!

-Chris

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to use [fully-qualified imports](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_mandatory_file_extensions) when feeding ES6 modules to Node.js.

In your case, this means adding the `.js` extension to your `schema` import:

```
 import express from 'express';
 import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
-import typeDefs from './schema/schema';
+import typeDefs from './schema/schema.js';
```

Your confusion likely comes from the fact that this requirement has changed between the traditional, `require()`-style references (called "CommonJS", and [detailed more here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules)), and the more modern ECMAScript Modules — but in the interim, a lot of tools that converted between one and the other would handle this problem *for* you (i.e. [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveenforceextension) and friends.) Now that these features are landing in a first-class fashion in Node, you're running into some *additional* things that older tools were Magically™ doing for you, but don't actually work that way in the spec!

Comment: is not working on my case :/

Comment: I don't think I've ever had a worst developer experience. I don't know how it can be this complicated to import a file and use it lol